# How to parse dynamically changing json in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I a have dynamically changing json like in below examples

Example 1:

```
"Flower":{
        "color": "red"     
}
```

Example 2:

```
"Flower":{
        "color": "red" ,
         "seasonal": "yes"    
}
```

Example 3:

```
"Flower":{
        "color": "red" ,
         "seasonal": {
              "seasons":{
                       "winter": "yes",
                         "summer" : "no"  
                        }        
                     }    
          }
```

and for the above examples output should be like

```
example1 : color:red
example2 :color:red,seasonal:yes
example3: color:red,seasonal.seasons.winter:yes,seasonal.seasons.summer:no
```

Problem here is dont know what comes everytime, it should be of output format. I need some piece of logic of this in javascript :(

Comment: If you really have no clue on what the structure is going to be, you can use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provide functions such as isObject and isString which will tell you if a variable is object or a string.

You can iterate through the properties of your object and check whether the property is an object or string. If it's an object then you can recurse the properties of that object, else just print it. Check the below.

```
$scope.iterate = function(object) {
if (!angular.isObject(object))
  return object;
var opt = "";
for (var property in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    opt = opt + property + " - " + $scope.iterate(object[property]) + " ";
  }
}
return opt;
}
```

You can also take a look at this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/Lvc0u55v/10999/), it has a working solution of the above code.

Comment: Thanks a ton pratik